# How can I display the activity when device is locked?

Tags: android, locking

I want to display one Activity Android, also when I lock my device.
Every Time, if I lock my tablet (for example), I should to see one Activity.

So, I have built this in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<activity
    android:name=".activity.SetupInfoEmergencyActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:showOnLockScreen="true"
    android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

This is the code of activity

```
public class SetupInfoEmergencyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON|
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD|
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED|
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.settings_activity);
    }

}
```

Now, if I try to run debug, I can see this activity, but if I un-lock my device, and I lock the device I can't see the activity.

Answer (score 2):

use this code in last of method onCreate

```
    //show if unlock
    final Window win = getWindow();
    win.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED
            | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
    win.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON
            | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON
            | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALLOW_LOCK_WHILE_SCREEN_ON);
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use an activity. Android will not show the lock screen behind your activity for security reason, so use service instead of Activity.

Below is my code in onStartCommand of my service.

```
WindowManager mWindowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);

View mView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.score, null);

WindowManager.LayoutParams mLayoutParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0, 0,
WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY,
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED
| WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD
| WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON
/* | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON */,
PixelFormat.RGBA_8888);

mWindowManager.addView(mView, mLayoutParams);
```

And add 
    uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" to manifest

This is copy from another similar post. I tried it real quick with a custom view and it worked well enough. Don't know what your intentions are for it though.

Comment: mmm, ok but with my code, I can see the activity when I lock my smartphone. But if I (for example) swich on the smartphone, it is locked, in this case, I would like to see also the activity/view/screen with my information